# How to type in new responsive design mode

Tags: firefox, responsive

In the new Firefox responsive design mode I cannot seem to type anything in a text field. When I try typing Firefox starts searching instead. When I go back to the old responsive design mode it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable "Search for text when you start typing" in settings -> general -> browsing.

Comment: This workaround works, but it should be noted that this is an obvious bug in Firefox, and not the intended behavior.